# Reading block by block from file then split test line by line

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

I am reading from a file into a buffer then I am dividing the read text into string where each text ends by a new line forms a new string.

Here is my code:

```
int ysize = 20000;
char buffer2[ysize];
int flag = 0;
string temp_str;
vector<string> temp;
while(fread(buffer2, ysize, 1, fp2)>0){
    //printf("%s", buffer2);
    std::string str(buffer2);
    //push the data into the vect
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    std::string::size_type prev = 0;
    /*means the last read did not read a full sentence*/
    if (flag == 1) {
        if (buffer[0] == '\n') {
          //this means we have read the last senstense correctly, directly go to the next
        }
        else{
            if((pos = str.find("\n", prev)) != std::string::npos){
                temp_str+=str.substr(prev, pos - prev);
                temp.push_back(temp_str);
                prev = pos + 1;
            }
            while ((pos = str.find("\n", prev)) != std::string::npos)
            {
                temp.push_back(str.substr(prev, pos - prev));
                prev = pos + 1;
            }

            // To get the last substring (or only, if delimiter is not found)
            temp.push_back(str.substr(prev));

            if (buffer2[19999] != '\n') {
                //we did not finish readind that query
                flag = 1;
                temp_str = temp.back();
                temp.pop_back();
            }
            else{
                flag = 0;
            }


        }
    }
    else{

        while ((pos = str.find("\n", prev)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            temp.push_back(str.substr(prev, pos - prev));
            prev = pos + 1;
        }

        // To get the last substring (or only, if delimiter is not found)
        temp.push_back(str.substr(prev));

        if (buffer2[19999] != '\n') {
            //we did not finish readind that query
            flag = 1;
            temp_str = temp.back();
            temp.pop_back();
        }
        else{
            flag = 0;
        }}
}
```

The problem is this doesn't read the data correctly, it almost eliminates half of text.

I'm not sure what I am missing in here. My idea is to read the data block by block then divide it line by line which is what is happing in the while loop. I am handling the overflow cases using the flag.

Comment: [`while (std::getline(myFileStream, lineStr)) {...}`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), and trust your `std::ifstream` implementation to do reasonable buffering.

Comment: I did that but the performance was horrible. I'm trying to read blocks of data to improve the performance which when I tested was a significant difference but dividing the strings is a bit of dilemma

Comment: I agree with BoBTFish, but maybe you can try `std::regex` or `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note, that *fread* does not magically create a null-terminated string, which means that *std::string str(buffer2)* will result in undefined behaviour. So you should do something like

```
int nread = 0; 
while( (nread =fread(buffer2, ysize-1, 1, fp2)) > 0 ){
    buffer2[nread] = 0; 
    std::string str(buffer2);
    ...
```

To avoid the buffering approach you implemented here you could use [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) to read line by line, then you would have only to worry about concatenating lines that are longer than the read buffer.

Apart from the I've spotted one problem: If the first char in the buffer is newline and *flag==1* you skip the whole current buffer and read the next one if there is still data available. (I assume that with *buffer[0]* you actually mean buffer2[0]).

Comment: Thanks!, I did not what do you mean by `buffer2[nread] = 0; ` , this will always removed my last read character and replace it with a 0, isn't it?  & fgets won't solve my problem, I trying to read more than one line at a time

Comment: No, because in C/C++ he indices are 0-based, hence when *nread* characters are read into buffer, they will be in *buffer[0]...buffer[nread-1]*, and with *buffer[nread]=0* you ensure the null-termination. 

As for *fgets* - yes I'm aware that you want to read more then one line in one go, but maybe *fgets* can save you some of the trouble to split the buffer later, and *fgets* also does some buffering, so it is likely that you will not lose performance by using it.